# How to Use AutoMapper for Find Method?

Tags: c#, automapper

How do I map this method using `AutoMapper`? Example:

```
public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Mapper.Map<Pais, PaisViewModel>( _paisService.Find(predicate));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a 1 to 1 mapping of simple objects then:

```
public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _paisService.Find(predicate).Select(p => Mapper.Map(p, Pais.GetType(), PaisViewModel.GetType()));
}
```

If the objects are complex or the properties are not 1 to 1 you will have to make calls to Map.CreateMap to define the object mapping.